# Super Simple View Engine (SSVE) @Context.ViewBag depth

Tags: viewengine, nancy

Is it possible to dive deep into objects stored in the ViewBag when using SSVE?

I have a "User" object placed on the ViewBag as such:

```
context.ViewBag.User = new { UserName = userByCookie.UserName };
```

When I try to access the UserName property from SSVE as such:

```
@Context.ViewBag.User.UserName
```

I get the error message:

> model must be a standard type or implement IDictionary
>   Parameter name: model

However; I when I access the "User" in SSVE as such:

```
@Context.ViewBag.User
```

I end up with the following output in my SSVE view:

> { UserName = Eric }

Can I access the sub-properties of a viewbag object when using SSVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phillip Haydon, ‏@philliphaydon, answered this question via Twitter:

> Sorry, it doesn't support depth. :(

https://twitter.com/philliphaydon/status/442842950431539200

Comment: NancyFx view engine rendering of any type (razor, spark, SSVE, etc) does not support any depth for ViewBag contents.

Comment: Assuming ViewBag.Page is an instance of PageModel, @ViewBag.Page.Foo.Bar seems to blow up in Nancy Razor, but @((PageModel)ViewBag.Page).Foo.Bar seems to work fine.